# how to handle System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 21

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset, datarow

i have a string which consist of data in XML format.it consist of different tag like in VENUE tag which have 50 data & ARTIST tag which consist of 20 data. My problem is when i bind that data in data set & adding that data in a data row i got error **There is no row at position 21** Here is my code

```
      for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Venue"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][1].ToString();
            dr["Address"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            dr["City"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][4].ToString();
            dr["State"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][5].ToString();
            dr["ZipCode"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][6].ToString();
            dr["Performer"] = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][0].ToString();
         }
```

1 for VENUE & 2 For ARTIST. How i handle this error because i want both VENUE & ARTIST data in a data table. Help me on this...

**EDIT**

i done this like

```
       if(ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count>0)
          { 
            dr["Performer"] = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][0].ToString();
          }
         else
          {
            dr["Performer"]="";
           }
```

but this doesn't work i gives me same error

**EDIT** what about this

```
          if (ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count > i)
            {
                dr["Performer"] = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                dr["Performer"] = "no performer";
            }
```

Comment: check whether ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][0] is not null before reading from it?

Comment: Is `ds.Tables[2]` correct or should it be `ds.Tables[1]`?

Comment: @Relax how to check before reading it ...

Comment: @TimSchmelter in XML 0 for EVENT tag

Comment: Your edit uses `ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count`, when it's `ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count` which is important...

Comment: sir, i edit my question.please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're *assuming* that `Tables[2]` has as many rows as `Tables[1]`, due to these two pieces of your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ...
    dr["Performer"] = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][0].ToString();
}
```

It's not clear what you're actually trying to do with the performer information, but it sounds like you may want to perform a join query, and work just on the joined rows.

Comment: the information is going to store in DB with the help of Stored Procedure

Comment: @rr11: That doesn't really explain what you're trying to do. Do you understand why it's not working? You've got two tables here, of different length... it's very odd to just take one row from each table, with no concept of a join between them.

Comment: sir, please see my second edit part.i achieved what i want. just want to know is it a good code or i have to do some other code because i am getting error on my first edit part i.e. on count

Comment: @rr11: We don't have nearly enough idea of what you're trying to do to judge whether that's appropriate or not. It doesn't sound like a good idea to me, to be honest - but without more context it's hard to help you.

Comment: @rr11: Again, that still sounds like you need a join. You should have *one* "table" (probably the result of a join) with that data in. The problem isn't a null value - it's not having enough rows... There's *no way whatsoever* that we can provide sample code with so little idea of what you're trying to do. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

              dr["Venue"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][1].ToString();

            dr["Address"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            dr["City"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][4].ToString();
            dr["State"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][5].ToString();
            dr["ZipCode"] = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][6].ToString();
             if(i<21){
              dr["Performer"] = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            }
         }
```

Try something like this instead of 21 put the count of the tags

Comment: He should check for null. This would be the safest way.

Comment: @llia this is not a feasible solution because if i got more than 21 performer then it will fail..

Comment: That's what I've told that you, instead of 21 put ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count, Also you can check on null as @Relax suggested

Comment: @llia i done this like 
if(ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count>0){ dr["Performer"] = ds.Tables[2].Rows[i][0].ToString();}else{dr["Performer"]="";}

Comment: ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count>0 if there is only one performer, your if statement will still be valid, ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count this value should be less or equal to i

Comment: @rr11: No, it's not a matter of checking for nullity - `ds.Tables[2].Rows[i]` will throw an exception. Checking for `ds.Tables[2].Count` would be safer.